# Address Field In PPP Protocol

Tags: networking, protocol-theory, layer2, ppp

What is the actual use of the Address Field on PPP As I know, it is always set to 11111111 and this doesn't seem to have any purpose because we use ppp we dealing with the direct link communication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have guessed the PPP address field was defined by [RFC 1662](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1662/) and has no function.  It must be all ones according to the RFC or it should be silently discarded.

```
   Address Field

      The Address field is a single octet, which contains the binary
      sequence 11111111 (hexadecimal 0xff), the All-Stations address.
      Individual station addresses are not assigned.  The All-Stations
      address MUST always be recognized and received.

      The use of other address lengths and values may be defined at a
      later time, or by prior agreement.  Frames with unrecognized
      Addresses SHOULD be silently discarded.
```

Even PPP in point to multipoint Frame Relay does not modify the PPP address field.

Comment: Is this one of those "future extensions" things for which the future never came? Like the version attribute in SDPs which is, has always been, and likely always will be `v=0`.